# What happened to 'too localized'?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Does the 'too localized' close reason still exist? I recently went to vote to close a question as too localized, but didn't see it.

Comment: It was removed maybe a year ago. Check m.se for an official post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like it was [removed network-wide a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons). When the close reasons were revamped, too localized was removed, as its use-cases were covered by new reasons, that sound better too. (Thanks Double AA for pointing me to MSE.)

Comment: Our custom "No p'sak" [close reason](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1733/2) is similar in meaning.